# How to resolve Node.js exec Promise on electron on windows after the .exe app is opened?

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to open an `.exe` installer application on electron.
But the `Promise` isn't resolved when the installer is opened, it only resolved if I close the installer or if the installation is finished.

This installer is an update file, so I have to close the electron app when the installer is opened.

Here is my code

```
let oppened = false;
if (process.platform === "win32") {
              oppened = await openExe(path);
            }
            if (oppened) app.exit();
```

```
const openExe = async (path: string): Promise<any> => {
  return await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    exec(`${path}`, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      if (error !== null) {
        console.log(error);
        resolve(false);
      } else {
        resolve(true);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) a `detached` process instead of using `exec`

```
const openExe = (exe: string, args: string[] = []) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const process = child_process.spawn(exe, args, {
        detached: true,
        stdio: "ignore"
      });
      process.on("error", error => {
        reject(error);
      });
      process.unref();

      if (process.pid !== undefined) {
        resolve(true);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}
```